# How to automatically minify html files in PhpStorm/ WebStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

For CSS files I have created a file watcher like described in this [manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/minifying-css.html). Also for JS files, see [manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/minifying-javascript.html), which both uses the YUI Compressor

But I didn't find how to add file watchers, which minify html files (e.g. removing comments, ..). How can I automatically minify html files with PhpStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [HTMLMinifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) - it has CLI and thus can be set up as a file watcher, also it can be configured as [Grunt task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) or [Gulp task](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin) and executed using Grant/Gulp console

Comment: I've never made a custom file watcher, could you help me with what to fill in at 'Program', 'Arguments' and 'Output paths to refresh'?

Comment: please see https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839385/phpstorm-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-html

Comment: it's in Russian, but includes screenshot + settings for 'argiuments', 'Output paths to refresh', etc.