# WebStorm File Watcher HTML minify

Tags: webstorm, html-minifier

I'm trying to minify my HTML document using a File Watcher and it does nothing.

I tried googling my problem and found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123772/how-to-automatically-minify-html-files-in-phpstorm-webstorm) from SO, I tried the solution that was in Russian but didn't work for me either.

Also, the working Dir is `$FileDir$`

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What doesn't work for you namely? The settings from [this SO link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839385/phpstorm-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-html) work fine for me with the most recent [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) version:

**Arguments:** `$FileName$ --collapse-boolean-attributes --collapse-whitespace --html5 --remove-attribute-quotes --remove-comments  --remove-empty-attributes --remove-optional-tags  --remove-redundant-attributes --remove-script-type-attributes  --remove-style-link-type-attributes --remove-tag-whitespace --sort-attributes --sort-class-name --trim-custom-fragments  --use-short-doctype --minify-js -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.html`

**Output paths to refresh:** `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.html`

**Working directory:** `$FileDir$`

[image]